# mysql complicated sql

Tags: mysql, select

I asked a question earlier today and received a good response that works well. There was a second part to the question that never got a response so I'm trying again.

```
SELECT q.id,q.question,a.question_id,a.answer, a.correct
FROM (SELECT * FROM questions q WHERE q.subject_id = 18
      ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5) q
JOIN answers a on q.id = a.question_id GROUP BY q.id, a.id
```

The above is fine and returns 5 random questions along with corresponding answers. The problem is that each question has 9 answers, 1 of which is correct (correct = 1) and the others are false (correct = 0). I don't want all the answers but rather the correct one and 3 other random ones.

I've been playing with this for hours and am getting nowhere.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Steve

PS: Maybe it's better to handle it via php but again I'm not sure. Any thoughts on that would be helpful too.

Comment: I had attempted on your other question but was never able to get a working solution.  Here's as far as I got, in case others want for reference: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/34906/34.  For some reason the `ORDER BY RAND()` in the inner query on `answers` is not working.

Comment: You'd be better in PHP. MySQL doesn't have the language constructs you can use in Oracle/SQL Server/PostgreSQL

Comment: @gbn: I agree, especially since there are only up to 9 answers per question.  It will be just as easy to pull all the answers into PHP and do the randomizing there.

Comment: @Gbn, incorrect about the constructs.  MySQL allows for inline SQL variables and I've used on MANY occasions to do this and other queries.

Comment: @DRapp: I mean SQL Standard ROW_NUMBER or CROSS APPLY constructs. Not non-standard MySQL workarounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is another example of a TOP X records per Y example.  For every question, you want 4 answers.  A LIMIT is actually needed TWICE... First to limit the qualifying questions, and another "ranking" of answers which guarantees the "Correct" answer to ALWAYS be included per question result set.

So my approach is to apply the random against questions first to get that as a subset result, then join that to the answers and limit X per Y.  THEN, we can get it all wrapped up.  The critical thing here is the inner query has to be ordered by the question ID... AND the qualifier the "Correct" answer is always in first position, but anything after is randomized to include a total of 4 records.

Then, the final query applies the WHERE clause to only include where the ranking sequence is <= 4 (of the possible all 9 answers included for 1 question, but then applies a final "ORDER BY" clause to keep the questions together, but randomizes the answers so the "Correct" is no longer always returned in the first position.  You can remove this outer "ORDER BY" clause for testing purposes just to confirm functionality, then add it back in later.

```
select
      FinalQA.*
   from
      ( select 
              QWithAllAnswers.*,
              @RankSeq := if( @LastQuestion = QWithAllAnswers.id, @RankSeq +1, 1 ) ARankSeq,
              @LastQuestion := QWithAllAnswers.id as ignoreIt
           from
              ( SELECT 
                      q.id,
                      q.question,
                      q.RandQuestionResult,
                      a.question_id,
                      a.answer, 
                      a.correct
                   FROM 
                      ( SELECT q.ID,
                               q.Question,
                               q.question_ID,
                               RAND() as RandQuestionResult
                           FROM 
                               questions q 
                           WHERE 
                               q.subject_id = 18 
                           ORDER BY RAND() 
                           LIMIT 5) JustQ
                      JOIN answers a 
                         on q.id = a.question_id
                   ORDER BY
                      JustQ.RandQuestionResult,
                      if( a.correct = 1,0.000000, RAND() 
              ) QWithAllAnswers,

              ( select @RankSeq := 0, @LastQuestion := 0 ) SQLVars

      ) FinalQA

   where
      FinalQA.ARankSeq < 5
   order by
      FinalQA.RandQuestionResult,
      rand()
```

Couple small changes... Make sure at the `SQLVars` has `:=` for each of the assignments.  When I originally posted, I left one ":" off which could have thrown a false error.  I also qualified the inner "Order by" by using "a.correct = 1" (had no alias reference).  Finally, changed the outer WHERE clause to just `< 5` instead of `<= 4`.   I've done MANY of these greatest X per Y groupings and know they work, just missing something simple I'm sure.

Also, adjusted the `IF()` random to have first value as a decimal, otherwise all randoms get set to 1 (whole number) and never fraction... Also for possible issues of when the ORDERING is applied, I've pre-queried all Q and A pre-sorted to get all Correct answers in the first position, THEN apply the `SQLVars` against that set, then finalize the rank sequence and ordering.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and got the following error... #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'QWithAllAnswers where QWithAllAnswers.ARankSeq <= 4 order by Q' at line 27

Comment: @user1292262, see comments of revised answer and sql adjustments.

Comment: I fixed some typos and built your solution here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/34906/52.  I know what example you modeled off of, and I had considered the same one.  But looks like it suffers from the exact same problems I had in my own solution I made and posted as a comment to OP.  It still doesn't randomize the answers for some odd reason, but just grabs the first four answers from each question.  So bizarre.  Maybe it's a problem just with sqlfiddle.com or the version of MySQL used there?  I don't have a MySQL instance myself available to test on...

Comment: @mellamokb, could you try again with revised query

Comment: @user1292262, I've adjusted per feedback from Mellamokb testing with sqlfiddle

Comment: @DRapp: Looks like it works! http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/34906/58.  All the difference in `if( a.correct = 1,0.000000, RAND() )`, how did you know that would do it?

Comment: @mellamokb,  When running a query and using a computed field, such as IF(), whatever value is returned the first time through sets the precidence of the final data type for the column.  So, if first time through was the correct answer, it was returning whole number 0.  Therefore, all remaining RAND() values would be SOMETHING, but all rounded to whole number.  By forcing the 0 to 0.000000 it allows the column to ALWAYS ANTICIPATE decimal base values supplied by RAND() to retain decimal precision.

Comment: @DRapp: Wow, very awesome, that would have fixed my query too.

Comment: Wow! That's amazing guys. I would have NEVER been able to figure that out and would have most likely just gone with the php solution. This solution is much better. What do you think about execution time? Will the sql be efficient enough?

Comment: @SteveF, execution time should be VERY quick, especially since you are pre-qualifying it for a specific subject, and only returning 5 tests per your example.  From that, it gets all possible answers for the question.  Say you have 20 answers possible per test, that's still ONLY 100 records to breeze through.

Comment: @DRapp, maximum number of questions to be returned will be 100. I guess it should still be ok. I'm developing my application using Yii, not sure if you're familiar with it, and am thinking how best to handle the data. I'm looking at query caching as the same user MUST  have the same dataset for the duration of their test. Any thoughts?

Comment: Should have mentioned each question will be displayed individually. So one question and associated answers per page. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @SteveF, even with 100 questions and even 10 questions per is 1,000 records which is STILL easy for MySQL to blow through and give you the final 400 records (100 questions, 4 answers each).

Comment: Sorry to bump an old post of mine but I was just wondering if anyone can adapt the sql to return the grouped questions in a random order rather than in question_id order like they are now. I've tried various things that I can think of but no luck so far.

Comment: @SteveF, see revision and look for instances of "RandQuestionResult"

Comment: @DRapp7 Thanks for the revision. I get an error though when I try it You  have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'QWithAllAnswers, ( select

Comment: @DRapp7 - I managed to figure it out. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @SteveF, so where was it so I can adjust my answer in case someone in the future can get something out of it.

Comment: @DRapp - was just the table names where you had JustQ.RandQuestionResult instead of q.RandQuestionResult

Comment: @SteveF, yes, my mistake as the RAND() was a result column that created the inner-most query "JustQ".  So you would order by the "JustQ" version of the column as it would remain the same value for rest of query downstream.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT q.id,q.question,a.question_id,a.answer, a.correct
FROM (SELECT * FROM questions q WHERE q.subject_id = 18
      ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5) q
JOIN answers a on q.id = a.question_id
ORDER BY q.id, a.correct, RAND()
```

That should get you the correct answer first and then the false answers in random order. This should make it easy for you to select 1 + 3 in your php code.

Edit: I removed your group by and put it in order by instead as you want one row pr answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use UNION to get the good answers and random incorrect answers?

```
SELECT q.id,q.question,a.question_id,a.answer, a.correct
FROM (SELECT * FROM questions q WHERE q.subject_id = 18
      ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5) q
  JOIN answers a on q.id = a.question_id 
WHERE a.correct = 0
GROUP BY q.id, a.id

UNION

SELECT q.id,q.question,a.question_id,a.answer, a.correct
FROM question q
  JOIN answers a on q.id = a.question_id 
WHERE q.subject_id = 18 
  AND a.correct = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try using subqueries, like:

(pseudocode)

```
Select a.*, q.*
from questions q join answers a on q.id=a.question_id
where q.id in ( SELECT id FROM questions q1 WHERE q1.subject_id = 18 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5 )
and a.id in ( SELECT id FROM answers a1 WHERE a1.question_id = q.id ORDER BY a1.correct desc, RAND() LIMIT 4)
```

(end pseudocode)

It might be more effective to read all answers, and pick the random 
ones in your code (still, they can be ordered by `correct` descending,
so that you know, the first one is the right one).

Comment: Thanks all for the help. Looks like the consensus is to randomize in php. I'll give that a go and see how I get on. The reason I want to grab all questions and answers in one go is because the questions must be unique so I can't get them one at a time. They have to be unique for the whole test. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: The simplest solution is actually to retrieve the questions in one query, and then, retrieve the answers for each question in a separate query.