# mysql complicated sql 2

Tags: mysql

I asked a question a few weeks ago about a complicated mysql statement and received a great response: [mysql complicated sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191535/mysql-complicated-sql)

There is a sql fiddle posting of the statement [here.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/34906/58)

Everything works great but I now have a requirement to extend/adapt the statement to select questions who either have the same subjects.parent_id or subjects.id

The subjects table is simple id,subject, parent_id  - if the parent_id is 0 then the subject itself is the parent. I need to return all questions with 4 random answers from both the subject (if it has no parent i.e parent_id = 0) and all the subjects that have it's id as parent_id. The current sql at sql fiddle returns the questions with random answers but only for a specific subject.

Hope that makes sense but if not please ask.

Thanks

Steve

Comment: I figured it out myself in the end. Was pretty simple. I just replaced the q.subject_id = subject_id with a 'in (select)' statement.